# Barcode scanner application in C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth, barcode-scanner

I am developing an application where it is required to scan the barcode and match it to the code stored in the database. My barcode scanner is cordless. I have written some code by which bluetooth devices can communicate. It's working for creating connection, but the problem is how do I receive the data. We are going to use multiple barcode scanners to one pc. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Is it possible to have multiple bluetooth scanners sending one data at the same time? How do I differentiate each of them?

Comment: Way more context needed!

Comment: Isn't there any sample code delivered with those scanners?

Comment: So what is the programming issue here, really?

Comment: edit your question, try use paragraphs, and less ...'s and ???'s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked with many wired and wireless scanners, and every single one did not need to be connected to directly, instead they all emulate keyboard presses.

Some over USB, others serial, or daisy-chaining into the PS2 port. Some needed their drivers installed, others are plug-and-play, but they all emulate key presses.

Check the scanner manual, it's vendor's site should have the latest.